# C# mvc razor textboxfor and passwordfor produce error when symbol < is entered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Specifically, when the user enters a letter after the less-than symbol "<", the client redirects to the generic error page, without the request ever reaching the corresponding action.

What is the best way to fix this issue?

**Update**
With the help of some answers and comments I realized that the actual error I get on the client is "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client "

But, the use of [AllowHtml] on all relevant fields does not seem as a best practice to me. Is there any other approach on this? (if not, I will accept the existing answer as the best one)

Comment: Its properly trying to protect you from XSS. Can you share some code? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/995931/Preventing-XSS-Attacks-in-ASP-NET-MVC-using-Valida

Comment: @Webbanditten, on the default mvc web application template of vs2013 the login screen reproduces this issue on user input with this symbol

Comment: Look [AllowHtml] on your property as mentioned below could be the solution. Also you would never display the password in raw HTML - plus the password is hopefully hashed so...

Comment: it is not a matter of the password field specifically. ANY text input field could expose the same problem. You suggest I use AllowHtml for any such field as a best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AllowHtml] attribute on the property of your model

Comment: this could be a solution, but raises some security issues. For example when the specific input is to be rendered in some page, the client could render some unsafe content...

Comment: When rendered the Html.Encode helper should be used on the content. That way the author can enable html in the form without errors but also has to encode it when displaying the content

Comment: Html.Encode is used already, as all fields are displayed with the @ razor helper. But what you are suggesting is that I use the AllowHtml attribute in ALL fields (as I do not now before where the user might want to use the < symbol) ? That does not seem as a best practice to me, as I do not actually want to allow Html (which the attribute denotes)